# Should I use GIF file or animation code on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, calayer

I intend to make a splash screen on iOS consists of a person, a chair objects. Each of these objects has seperated aspects like the hands, head, body and feets that animated together. I wonder which is better way to go? Importing a GIF file or coding CALayer objects then adding animation?

Comment: it depends only on which resource you'd like to sacrifice for committing the task: the _time_ or the _memory_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use GIF files or any code for animation for your launchscreen (splash screen), you can only use a static image, a PNG or JPG (if the launchscreen is a storyboard).

So, if you want your app's startup with some animation then you should manage it in your first view controller.

You can animate `imageview` with image sets like,

```
UIImageView* myImageViewForAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
myImageViewForAnimation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"], nil];
myImageViewForAnimation.animationDuration = 1.0f;
myImageViewForAnimation.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[myImageViewForAnimation startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: myImageViewForAnimation];
```

**Update (as asked in comment) :**

You can get your view on which you have added `gesture recognizer` in your action method or you can set `tag` to every `imageview` and handle it in action method.

For example,

```
 -(void)tapOnProfileImage : (UITapGestureRecognizer*)recog{


UIImageView *tempView = (UIImageView *)recog.view;

// or

if (recog.view.tag == 1) {

    // image 1
}

if (recog.view.tag == 2) {
    //image 2
}
}
```

So, on every image view, you should `add target with selector - tapOnProfileImage` and you can differentiate it as mentioned in above code snippet!

Comment: I'd like navigate the user to different screen for different image that they have tapped on. So how to determine which image is tapped on?

Comment: add `tapgesturerecognizer` on image and you can handle tap on action method

Comment: your suggestion just for detecting user interaction but how to determine which image the user has tapped on? Please keep giving a guide to me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use gif image but not directly on launch xib. You create one view controller and load gif image on that view controller, once animation is completed then remove this controller from navigation stack. https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage use this gif image view control.